# Заполнить один список в зависимости от другого

Tags: алгоритм

У меня есть список товаров. Количество товаров кратно 3 и лежит в диапазоне от 3 до 15. Я ввожу число товаров и проставляю им рейтинг от 1 до 10. Затем, исходя из рейтинга, я должен проставить им цену 1$, 2$ или 3$, так чтобы число денег было одинаковым.

Привожу пример.
6 товаров с рейтингом
[1 6 8 2 9 3]
Таблица с деньгами будет такой
[1$ 2$ 3$ 1$ 3$ 2$]

Каким алгоритмом эту зависимость реализовать?

Comment: Что значит "исходя из рейтинга"? По какому принципу решается какому рейтингу какая цена соответствует?

Comment: решил. сделал по такому принципу. делаю клон списка и для него получаю отсортированный список. 
[1 2 3 3 8 9]
соответственно к нему создаю хэшмап
[(1|1$)(2|1$)(3|2$)(3|2$)(8|3$)(9|3$)]
а затем в цикле проходу на соответствие старый список - и ему значение из мапа.